# How to make an array to not repeat?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, shuffle

Here is my code for a simple game. paste it and try it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    string  g[4],
    b[4],
    a[4],
    l[4];

    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    cout << "Welcome!\n\n";
    cout << "Type 4 girl names.\n";
    for (int gi = 0; gi < 4; gi++) 
        cin >> g[gi];

    cout << "Type 4 boy names.\n";
    for (int bi = 0; bi < 4; bi++)
        cin >> b[bi];

    cout << "\nWhat they do (enter 4 actions)?\n";
    for (int ai = 0; ai < 4; ai++)
        getline(cin, a[ai]);

    cout << "\nWhere is happening (enter 4 locations)?\n";
    for (int li = 0; li < 4; li++)
        getline(cin, l[li]);

    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        cout << g[rand() % 4] << " and " << b[rand() % 4] << " are " << a[rand() %     4] << " from a " << l[rand() % 4] << endl;

    return (0);
}
```

At the end in the 4 lines some of the names, actions and locations repeat. How do I make them to not repeat and use every name that you will enter?

Comment: They repeat because you pick them randomly. So in order to stop the repeating, stop picking them randomly.

Comment: I need the random function to randomly pick a name, action or location , here is the problem.

Comment: A solution would be [random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) on your arrays

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::random_shuffle`:

```
std::random_shuffle(g, g + 4);
std::random_shuffle(b, b + 4);
std::random_shuffle(a, a + 4);
std::random_shuffle(l, l + 4);
```

And then just iterate over all of the shuffled arrays:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    cout << g[c] << " and " << b[c] << " are " << a[c] << " from a " << l[c] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    cout << g[rand() % 4] << " and " << b[rand() % 4] << " are "
         << a[rand() %     4] << " from a " << l[rand() % 4] << endl;
```

You've made an assumption that consecutive calls to `rand()` are guaranteed to *not* yield the same result as previous calls to `rand()`, but this is baseless.

Thus, there is always a possibility that you will get repeats; in fact, there is a 1 in 64 chance that you will get *the same answer each time*.

Either remove the randomness, or perform a random array shuffle before the loop ([as demonstrated by Mr @Eladidan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921546/560648)). Or, create an array of the numbers `0,1,2,3`, shuffle *that*, then use it as indexes into your data arrays.

It's the nature of random *shuffling* (rather than random *extraction*) that'll give you a non-repeating answer.